# Add limited spaces depend on name in regular expression using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have one regular expression for Full Name Validation,but I want name should start with alphabates and space (it depends on name) with limit like 50 (not more than 50):

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

This is working but but here no limit, how to add limit and spaces (depends on name)?

Comment: What are you trying to say? Explain with examples

Comment: how space would come first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the `name` to max 50 characters:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]{,50}$
```

Here `{,50}` will match for maximum of 50 preceding characters.

`\s` will match any space character.

**EDIT**

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,50}$/;
....
if (reg.test($(this).val())) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xcr2hgk9/

Comment: any no. of spaces Max- 50 when no alphabet

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xcr2hgk9/ Check demo and updated answer

Comment: suppose instaed of \s,if i put some space,will it work?

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra YES! work for space only and not for tabs and other space characters

Answer (score 2):

To force the first symbol to be an English letter or a space, and the following 49 characters can be any (but a newline), you can use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z ].{49}$
```

If you want to just limit the input to English letters and spaces, you just need to add the [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,50}` meaning *from 1 up to 50 occurrences of the preceding subpattern*:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]{1,50}$
```

Adapting to your code and coding style, here is how you can use the second regex:

```
if($(this).attr('id') === "FullName") {
    var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]{1,50}$");
    if(!re.test($(this).val())) {
        res = "FullName is Not Valid"; alertDispaly(res);   
    }
}
```

To apply further restrictions, e.g. *do not end in a space*, you can use `^[a-zA-Z ]{1,49}[a-zA-Z]$`. Or, *no double space allowed*: `^(?!.*  )[a-zA-Z ]{1,49}[a-zA-Z]$`.

**EDIT**: To allow tabs, newline characters, and other whitespace, you can add `\\s` to your pattern, e.g.:

```
    var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\\s]{1,50}$");
```

You need to use `\s` in literal regex notation, and `\\s` in a RegExp constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]{0,50}$
```

http://regexr.com/3b3o2